# problem with geometry_msgs.Twist on Android

Tags: ros, android-gingerbread, rosjava, geometry-msgs, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking at the [VirtualJoystickView.java](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/android_honeycomb_mr2/src/org/ros/android/view/VirtualJoystickView.java?repo=android) in the Honeycomb example I tried to do similar thing on Gingerbread, however I was getting NullPointerException when trying to access currentVelocityCommand variable which is of type geometry_msgs.Twist.

Looking at the code of Twist.java it turns it's an interface. To implement Twist I also need to implement Vector3, and I'm now stuck with toRawMessage() method.

This is probably the wrong path and surely I'm missing something obvious.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34076/problem-with-geometry_msgs.twist-on-android/) by [Artjom](https://answers.ros.org/users/2386/artjom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turned out I was on the wrong path. Everything is in the documentation. All I had to do was just use the MessageFactory and create the message of the Twist type. Everything works as expected now.

---

Originally posted by [Artjom](https://answers.ros.org/users/2386/artjom/) with karma: 26 on 2012-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-05-21**:
You should use the convenience methods like Publisher.newMessage() where possible.

**Comment by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on 2012-06-02**:
Hi Artjom, I am also having the same null pointer exception problem you had when using Twist. In fact, the null pointer exception occurs even with the sample code "android_tutorial_teleop" provided with android_core. Do you mind letting me know what you did to solve the problem successfully? Thanks.